# Confusion about using YouTube Data API from the server or the client

Tags: youtube-api

I am building a website which uses the YouTube Data API. I am new to using such APIs.

My need:-

I need to receive videos and show its thumbnails.

My problem:-

If I use JavaScript to receive videos (I mean, from the client side), then my API KEY will be exposed.

My solution:-

I will use my server for such requests (to the YouTube Data API) and my client side will receive the YouTube Data API response through AJAX to my server.

So, my solution worth the problem?

Comment: Since it's the only secure solution, yes ? You can't provide your access to the client side, so ofc all the requests towards the youtube-api should be done trought your server that will then handle the data and send it to your client.

Comment: Thanks xoxel! Appreciate your time. At least someone helped me otherwise I would die the next day.

Comment: No problem, also this isn't "help" this is advice, YOU came up with the solution to your problem, i simply approved it ! So don't let the fact that you got no answers disgust you from SO, the site is a gold-mine of knowledge and help seeking, yet your question is not "really" a question, more of a pair-review thing (?) and that's the reason why nobody answered. If you ever have an algorithm problem you can't figure how to resolve, come here with some proof that you indeed tried, you code, the expected and current behavior, and everyone will be glad to help :).